# Javafx - Running Task from initialize method stops immediately

Tags: javafx, concurrency, task

I am some junior in Java and after didn't find answers in other posts, so decided asking for help.
Target: Need to run inside initialize() method in JavaFx application with below Controller code:

```
package myAlgo;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

public class Controller{

    @FXML
    String connectionstatus="";
    @FXML
    private Connection connection;
    @FXML
    private TextField connectionStatusTextField;
    @FXML
    Task<Void> task; 


@FXML
public void initialize() {
    connection = new Connection();
    checkConectionStatus();
}   


@FXML
public void checkConectionStatus() {
        task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override protected Void call() throws Exception {  
                        while(!isCancelled()) {

              connectionstatus=String.valueOf(connection.checkConnection());
                        connectionStatusTextField.setText(connectionstatus);
                            Thread.sleep(3000);
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                };
    Thread th = new Thread(task);
        th.setDaemon(true);
        th.start();
}
```

As result the Task inside inialize method is starting running, but stops immediately.

After debuging got java.lang.NullPointerException from FutureTask.class in run() method on row of connection.checkConnection() class at row of "return" in:

```
public boolean checkConnection() {
     return client.isConnected();
}
```

P.S.
If running it from anouther method - the Task is running without problem.
Tried running after encapsulating by service from (javafx.concurrent.Service), but got the same result.

Comment: Did you check if it's failing/the `exception` property?

Comment: So is it `client` that is `null`? If so, check how you initialize the object. It could be you set the `client` after the FXML files have been loaded.

Comment: `Task` or not, you must not modify the gui from a thread other than the JavaFX application thread. (In this case you could use `connectionStatusTextField.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());` outside of the task and `updateMessage(connectionstatus);` inside the `call` method instead of setting the text of the textfield.) Also we don't know, if the `TextField` is injected properly and it's unclear how your `Connection` class is implemented.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, the problem happened because of client class was not created and after adding it to constractor of connection class - the problems was solved, but the question is  why it ws worked after calling  checkConectionStatus() from anouther method inside Controller?!